# Bind meeting room to meeting EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to bind a meeting room when creating a meeting with EWS ?

Right now I am creating the meeting like this :

```
var appointment = new Appointment(service)
{
    Subject = "Status Meeting",
    Body = "The purpose of this meeting is to discuss status.",
    Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
    End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).AddHours(2),
    RequiredAttendees = { "test@test.com" }
};
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

But I cannot make it to bind to a specific room (Ex: `myRoom@myOrg.onmicrosoft.com`).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the meeting room as a [resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.resources(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Add the code below just before your `appointment.Save` code.

```
appointment.Resources.Add("myRoom@myOrg.onmicrosoft.com");
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you !